# which usb antivirus is better for cleaning virus that hides files and also remove important.exe

Tags: windows-xp, usb, virus, anti-virus

i have a big problem. my USB-flash is infected by a virus that hides my files. every time i connect my USB-flash to my PC the files will be hide. there is another more virus. important.exe.
i need a light and powerful antivirus that remove all USB related viruses and guarantee to keep my USB-flash protected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the antiviruses can remove virus related to USB. But each virus is programmed differently so, it is hard to alter the effect of it (in your case hidden folders).

Here are couple of things that you can do:

- Open '**run**' box and run "**msconfig**" command. In the Startup tab, remove the irrelavent programs from the list. (remove all other programs except programs related to Video and sound drivers). Then restart your computer. This will prevent the virus program from running at startup.
- Open My computer and go to Tools -> Folder Options. In the view tab:

  1. Select **Show hidden files and folders**.
  2. Uncheck **Hide protected operating system files (recommended)**.
- Now open your USB flash drive and you'll see actual hidden folders there, copy/use the data from there. Then format your flash drive. Check other computer drives too. If there is a .bat file or unrecognised .exe file there, delete them too.
- Install a good antivirus (google top 10 antivirus and use anyone of them (I use **avira** free)). And scan your whole computer for other traces of virus.

Comment: Duplicate answer for a duplicate question.